# Error: expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error, why does it expect the parameter to not be a boolean? How do I fix this? (I know this is a common error, so I want to understand WHY it comes up, so that I can hopefully fix it on my own when it comes up again.)

Warning: mysqli_stmt_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\Users\James\Desktop\Container\XAMPP\htdocs\Triiline1\signupuser.php on line 20

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Signup</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'connect.php';


//if submit is clicked
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //then check if all fields are filled
    if (empty($_POST['username']) | empty($_POST['password']) | empty($_POST['firstname']) | empty($_POST['MI']) | empty($_POST['lastname']) | empty($_POST['email']) | empty($_POST['phonenumber']) | empty($_POST['country']) ) {
        echo('You did not complete all of the required fields'); }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $usernamesquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username='$username'");
    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($usernamesquery) > 0) {
        die('This username is already taken.');
    }


} ?>
<form action="" method="post">

Username: <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30"><br>
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="30"><br>
Middle Initial: <input type="password" name="MI" maxlength="30"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="30"><br>
Email: <input type="password" name="email" maxlength="50"><br>
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phonenumber" maxlength="11"><br>
Country: <input type="password" name="country" maxlength="40"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're mixing mysql and mysqli. Also, apparently your query fails, and returns a boolean false.

Comment: Your query failed and it returned `boolean (false)` instead of a result set.

Comment: I assume mysql_query returns false because something failed instead of a result set.

Comment: As all the other questions you found probably say: add some debugging (error messages etc) to your code: you'd probably find out you don't have a database connection, your query returns an error (e.g.: false), or something like that.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation to see when `mysql_query` returns `false`? Or reading the answers to the gajillion existing "mysql_query returns false" questions on SO?

Comment: I fixed it all to mysqli and now it's changed the error message:

Warning: mysqli_stmt_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, object given in C:\Users\James\Desktop\Container\XAMPP\htdocs\Triiline1\signupuser.php on line 20 (The same error except object given instead of boolean given)

I believe I have an error message in my connection.

Comment: If you fixed your code, update the code in your question so we can see it. And read the documentation... The page for `mysqli_query` has an example with result row counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mysql_*` in this statement instead of `mysqli_*`

```
$usernamesquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username='$username'");
```

Try:

```
$usernamesquery = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username='$username'");
```

**EDIT**

You need to use `mysqli_num_rows($usernamesquery)` instead of `mysqli_stmt_num_row(...)` in your current implementation:

`mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` is used as:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query)) {

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* store result */
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));

}
```

Comment: What should $connection = ?

Comment: `$connection` is your database connection object. It is returned by `mysqli_connect()`. For example: `$connection = mysqli_connect(...)`. It should be in your `connect.php` or you have to save the connection if its not there.

Comment: Okay, I did that, now it's saying:

Warning: mysqli_stmt_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, object given in C:\Users\James\Desktop\Container\XAMPP\htdocs\Triiline1\signupuser.php on line 20

(The same error except object given instead of boolean given)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use either `mysqli` or `mysql` dont mix up..you are using both

```
$usernamesquery = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username='$username'");
if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($usernamesquery) > 0) {
    die('This username is already taken.');
}
```